# Kill service with looping sound file

Tags: android, loops, audio, service, intentservice

I have a sound file running in a loop on a service.

The activity that starts the service also has a button. When I press the button I want the sound file in the service to stop playing, i.e kill the service. Have been unsuccessful so far as when I call `stopService()` the service continues to run.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

**Activity**

```
public class AlarmPage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_page);
    TextView timeview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timefiled);
    final Button dismissButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.dismissButton);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String hrval = b.getString("HR");
    String minval = b.getString("MN");
    timeview.setText(hrval + ":" + minval);

    final Intent alarmring = new Intent(this, alarmringService.class);

    startService(alarmring);
    dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent alarmmenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SetAlarmsActivity.class);
            startActivity(alarmmenu);

            System.out.println("Button:" + dismissButton.isPressed());
            stopService(alarmring);

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alarm_page, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

---

**Service**

```
public class alarmringService extends IntentService{

public alarmringService(){
    super("alarmringService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.startrekcommsound);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    mp.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why it doesn't work since I'm not an expert, but to fix your problem you could use intents. By the way, `IntentService` stops itself when it has no more work!

Try this: Send to the `IntentService` an Intent with a command saying to stop itself.
Then in `onHandleIntent()` check if this was the request and call `stopSelf()` from inside the `Service`.

Moreover, I don't know how `MediaPlayer` works, but maybe it has his own thread and you should stop this thread too!